# Как найти корень квадратный в Python?

Tags: python

В Python 2.7.8 не получается найти корень квадратный и экспоненту.

Comment: http://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-math.html

Comment: @Валентина, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Как уже написали ранее, можно воспользоваться функциями из стандартного модуля `math`. Для этого его нужно подключить к программе. Использование выглядит следующим образом:

```
import math

x = float(input())
print(math.sqrt(x))
print(math.exp(x))
```

При желании можно использовать и без префикса, в таком случае можно использовать другой синтаксис импорта:

```
from math import sqrt, exp

x = float(input())
print(sqrt(x))
print(exp(x))
```

---

Для того, чтобы найти квадратный корень, можно ещё использовать оператор возведения в степень или функцию `pow` (так как квадратный корень это возведение в степень 0.5):

```
x = float(input())
print(x ** 0.5)
print(pow(x, 0.5))
```

[Обсуждение способов взятия корня с использованием `pow`, `** 0.5`, `math.sqrt` на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327002/which-is-faster-in-python-x-5-or-math-sqrtx)

Answer (score 2):

```
math.exp
math.sqrt
```

Comment: не получается!

Comment: я так тоже думала

Comment: @Валентина, объясните подробней, что именно не получается. Покажите код, который Вы пытаетесь запустить, что происходит при запуске.

Comment: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> a=input()
0.5
>>> b=input()
10
>>> x=sqrt(float(a))/exp(float(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined
>>>

Comment: я поняла, надо указывать math при каждом обращении к функциям. Тогда работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @Валентина, не обязательно. Если сделать не просто `import math`, а `from math import exp, sqrt`, то можно вызывать sqrt и exp без префикса math:

    >>> from math import exp, sqrt
    >>> sqrt(0.5)
    0.7071067811865476
    >>> exp(10)
    22026.465794806718

Answer (score 1):

**Square root:**
100 ** 0.5

**Square:**
10 ** 2

Answer (score 0):

```
math.sqrt(a/b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = float(input())

print(pow(100, 0.5))
```

Comment: И что выведет, если например ввести 4, не подскажите?